# Deploy Rails App to Elastic Beanstalk while autorunning npm and Bower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Rails app to Elastic Beanstalk using the CLI. The rails app deploys fine (asset compilation, db migration, etc.). However, I'm not able to run `bower install`. I tried running `sudo npm install -g bower` and it installs to \opt, but when trying to run a bower command it doesn't recognize bower as being installed in the system.

These are my questions:

1) Why isn't bower accessible from my app directory? 
2) How do I get it so that EB automatically runs `rake bower:install` (I'm using the bower-rails gem to be compatible with the asset pipeline)? 
3) How do I get it so that EB automatically installs npm so that part 2 will work above?

Thank you and hopefully my question makes sense. (Relatively new to AWS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a better solution. Rather than using the Bower Rails gem, just use a standard bower.json file in the root directory.

Then, create a config file: .ebextension/ruby-settings.config with the following contents:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03_bower_install.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo "starting to install bower via npm"
      sudo npm install bower -g --prefix /usr/local --allow-root
      echo "starting to install git"
      sudo yum install git
      echo "changing directory to /var/app/ondeck"
      cd /var/app/ondeck
      ls
      echo "running bower install"
      sudo $(which bower) install --allow-root
```

This utilizes elastic beanstalk's pre deploy hooks, and allows installation of bower and `bower install` to run **before** asset precompilation.

Comment: It works. But during bower install eb throw `events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event` error. Anyone fixed it?